# Every closed set is a boundary

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

**Prove/Disprove**: for all closed $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists some $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t $$\partial A=S$$
I've tried defining $$A=\partial S\uplus\left(\mathbb{Q}^{n}\cap\text{int}(S)\right)$$
because intuitively it feels to me like it would satisfy the equality, but i did not succeed in proving that $\partial A=S$.

Comment: Consider $S =$ a closed ball.

Comment: @IH How about $S\cap\mathbb Q^n$?

Comment: @xpaul How about $S\cap\mathbb Q^n$?

Comment: @Stinking Bishop Ah, I see. Now this question seems indeed interesting.

Comment: I think the OP is well aware of this approach with intersecting with $\mathbb Q^n$. It seems to work. Does it work in all cases, or are there counterexamples? That is the question here.

Comment: Here's a different approach to try: Let $B$ be a countable base for $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $U_n\in B$ such that $U_n\cap S \neq \emptyset$, pick an element $x_n\in U_n\cap S$. The set of all these $x_n$ should be a good candidate for $A$.

Although I see Florian has given a proof that your answer works.

Comment: I'm skeptical of this $\Bbb Q^n$ approach. What if $S$ is a segment of a curve that contains no rational points?

Comment: @BrandonduPreez That your approach works can even be proved much quicker!

Comment: @Karl That is why it's important to include $\partial S$ in the set $A$. That takes care of it.

Comment: Oh, I see. In my example you get $A=S$, which works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you verify the following two facts?

(i) The set $A$ as you defined has empty interior.

(ii) The closure of the set $\mathbb{Q}^n \cap \mathrm{int}(S)$ is the closure of $\mathrm{int}(S)$.

Then you can conclude as follows:
$$ \partial A = \bar{A} \backslash \mathrm{int}(A) = \bar{A} = \overline{\partial S \cup (\mathbb{Q}^n \cap \mathrm{int}(S))} = \overline{\partial S} \cup \overline{\mathbb{Q}^n \cap \mathrm{int}(S)} = \partial S \cup \overline{\mathrm{int}(S)} = S. $$

If you'd like to see a proof of the two facts, I'll gladly add them.